# contract compilation of 'eosio.bios' fails

Tags: eosio.cdt, eosio.system, compilation, eosiocpp

I am trying to setup Local Multi-Node Testnet using the version 2.0.7.

Clone the sysytem contracts from the repo as follows.

```
      git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts --branch master --single-branch
```

Creating wasm and abi files using the following command.

```
      cd eosio.contracts/contracts/eosio.bios
      eosio-cpp -I include -o eosio.bios.wasm src/eosio.bios.cpp --abigen
```

But it generates the following compilation error.

```
    In file included from /home/user/eosio/eosio.contracts/contracts/eosio.bios  /src/eosio.bios.cpp:1:
    include/eosio.bios/eosio.bios.hpp:237:50: error: no member named  'producer_authority' in namespace 'eosio'
         void setprods( const std::vector<eosio::producer_authority>& schedule );
                                      ~~~~~~~^
   /home/user/eosio/eosio.contracts/contracts/eosio.bios/src/eosio.bios.cpp:34:47:  error: no member named 'producer_authority' in namespace 'eosio'
      void bios::setprods( const std::vector<eosio::producer_authority>& schedule ) {
                                   ~~~~~~~^
   /home/user/eosio/eosio.contracts/contracts/eosio.bios/src/eosio.bios.cpp:50:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'preactivate_feature'
   preactivate_feature( feature_digest );
   ^
     /home/user/eosio/eosio.contracts/contracts/eosio.bios/src/eosio.bios.cpp:54:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'is_feature_activated'
   check( is_feature_activated( feature_digest ), "protocol feature is not activated" );

    4 errors generated.
    abigen error
```

Did anyone face this similar issue?Help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a single contract with eosio.cdt you would need to modify the code.

Just use the build-script **build.sh** (located in the eosio.contracts-directory) to compile all system-contracts at once, without the need to modify any of them.

Comment: I have updated the version of 'eosio.cdt' to 1.7.0 and able to successfully compile the contracts using 'build.sh'